# Can we pass more than 5 values with parameterized queries in DocumentDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I just read the blog post from Ryan CrawCour that DocumentDb now supports parameterized queries and that we can even pass arrays or nested JSON.

Does this mean I can use this approach to pass more than 5 values in a query? There seems to be a limit of 5 AND's or OR's in a DocumentDb query.

Here's a scenario:
I have a list of 20 EmployeeId's. I'd like to retrieve their information e.g. name, email, etc from my collection. Can I now retrieve their information in a single query by using a parameter that contains these 20 ID's?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite; there is still a limit of 5 AND's and OR's. The SQL parameterization changes just add handling and escaping of user input to help protect you against SQL injection attacks.

Today, you will need to issue multiple queries to retrieve a list of 20 employee id's. You can avoid making a bunch of round trips to the service by creating a stored procedure and passing an array to it.

Pls help voice your opinion and vote for "in" on the azure feedback forums to get this feature prioritized:
http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6395357-in-operator

Answer (score 0):

Now the IN clause is introduced, and because it queries based on one indexed field, it is limited to 100 values, which should be enough for most use cases. So you can get the employee document with one DocDb call.
You can look at:
https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo